# SQL - How can I get the name of a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the name of a specific column. I only found the function to get ALL column names:

```
select Column_name 
from Information_schema.columns 
where Table_name like 'table name'
```

Is it possible to select a specific column?
For example if I have a table with 10 columns, I want to get the column "firstname".

Comment: Just add the condition in where `and Column_name  like 'firstname'`

Comment: I'm curious why you need this? If you have the column name already, why are you querying for it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is:

```
select Column_name 
from Information_schema.columns 
where Table_name = 'table name'
and COLUMN_NAME = '<your column name>'
```